# QGIS : how can I keep data while removing the source file?

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, save, data-management

I imported some .kmz files to QGIS as vector layers.
Now, I want to keep this data but remove the files : I want the data to be stored (baked) in the qgis file itself.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Babel's answer covers it.  But if all you meant by saying you "want the data to be stored in the qgis file" is that you want the data to remain as layers in your project, then you could just use the save as command to save your kmz files to new shapefiles or geopackage layers, and then add these to your project and save it.   Then delete the kmz. If you applied some symbology, filters, legend items to the kmz layers that you want to keep, after saving your kmzs to the new  datasets you could use the change DataSource plugin to point your project layers to the new and save the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't save data inside of the QGIS project file. Using QGIS, project and data are always stored separately.

What you can do, however, is to save the project plus data file to the same Geopackage file. Geopackage works like a container format and can store everything in one single file that can be saved out of QGIS.

This can be handy when you want to share a project with local date with someone else. However, when working on your own machine, I would recommend to keep data and project files separately.